# Storing large amounts of compile time constant data

Tags: c++

I hope that this question hasn’t been asked before, but I couldn’t find any answer after googling for an hour.

I have the following problem: I do numerical mathematics and I have about 40 MB of `doubles` in the form of certain matrices that are compile time constants. I very frequently use these matrices throughout my program. The creation of these matrices takes a week of computation, so I do not want to compute them on the fly but use precomputed values.

What is the best way of doing this in a portable manner? Right now I have some very large CPP-files, in which I create dynamically allocated matrices with the constants as initialiser lists. Something along the lines:

data.cpp:

```
namespace // Anonymous
{

// math::matrix uses dynamic memory internally
const math::matrix K { 3.1337e2, 3.1415926e00, /* a couple of hundred-thousand numbers */ };

}

const math::matrix& get_K() { return K; }
```

data.h

```
const math::matrix& get_K();
```

I am not sure if this can cause problems with too much data on the stack, due to the initialiser list. Or if this can crash some compilers. Or if this is the right way to go about things. It does seem to be working though.

I also thought about loading the matrices at program startup from an external file, but that also seems messy to me.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: what is `math::matrix` ? You first write that it uses dynamically allocated memory but then ask for enough space on the stack. What is it? Why loading from file "seems messy" ?

Comment: Do you want to recompile when `K` changes or load a different file? Thats the choice you have to make and what would be part of what you call "best"

Comment: K is truly a constant, just like pi, it will never change. So it feels like right to put it into the source code.

The reason why I ask about the stack: I mean these numbers need to be stored in the executable binary at some place. I don’t know where this happens, or if this causes any problems.

Comment: never say never. If the matrix is the result of some other calculation you might also want to rerun that other calculation at some point. Also running the same algorithm with different input just for testing is necessary sometimes. I'd go for reading a file, but thats just based on the limited information i have

Comment: Big static stuff should be put in resource files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not sure if this can cause problems with too much data on the stack, due to the initialiser list.

There should not be a problem assuming it has static storage with non-dynamic initialisation. Which should be the case if `math::matrix` is an aggregate.

Given that the values will be compile time constant, you might consider defining them in a header, so that all translation units can take advantage of them at compile time. How beneficial that would be depends on how the values are used.

> I also thought about loading the matrices at program startup from an external file

The benefit of this approach is the added flexibility that you gain because you would not need to recompile the program when you change the data. This is particularly useful if the program is expensive to compile.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That eased my mind. One of the reasons why I do not want to read it from an external file is that I would need to write code to check for I/O-errors, which I can simply avoid this way.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly cleaner approach:

```
// math::matrix uses dynamic memory internally
const math::matrix K { 
   #include "matrix_initial_values.h"
};
```

And, in the included header,

```
3.1337e2, 3.1415926e00, 1,2,3,4,5e6, 7.0,...
```

Considering your comment of "A few hundred thousand" float values: 1M `double` values takes 8,000,000 bytes, or about 7.6MB. That's not going to blow the stack. Win64 has a max stack size of 1GB, so you'd have to go really, really nuts, and that's assuming that these values are actually placed on the stack, which they *should not be* given that it's `const`.

This is probably implementation-specific, but a large block of literals is typically stored as a big chunk of code-space data that's loaded directly into the process' memory space. The identifier (`K`) is really just a label for that data. It doesn't exist on the stack or the heap anymore than code does.

Comment: The default stack size on windows is 1MB, so custom configuration would be required to fit all of that on the stack. And it's important to remember that the array would share space with all other automatic variables as well. That said, it would be a problem only if the array is actually stored on the stack.

Comment: I googled some more and found that the unix tool ‘size’ lists how big the contents of an object file actually are. Running that on my compiled data.cpp in-deed shows that almost everything is in the text segment. Thank you!